# How do you get input while using a multi-part string?

Tags: python

I have some code, something along the lines of

```
name = input("What is your name?")
press_enter_to_continue = input("Well", name, ", you've got a long journey ahead of you.")
```

I end up getting an error over the surplus of parameters, so I how could I redo the code?

Comment: The `+` operator is used for string concatenation in python

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
press_enter_to_continue = input("Well {} you've got a long journey ahead of you.".format(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways to add a variable to a string:

```
input("Well {}, you've got a long journey ahead of you.".format(name))
```

If you're using python 3.6 you can do:

```
input(f"Well {name}, you've got a long journey ahead of you.")
```

Or if you want ot keep it super simple:

```
input("Well " + name + ", you've got a long journey ahead of you.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using string formatting, you can use the `+` operator to concatenate the strings.

```
name = input("What is your name?")
press_enter_to_continue = input("Well" + name + ", you've got a long journey ahead of you.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the strings using +, although Ajax1234's answer is a better option:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
press_enter_to_continue = input("Well" + name + ", you've got a long journey ahead of you.")
```